# Find det A and det B

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

So i was given the question

> If $A$ is $3 \times 3$ matrix and $\det (2A^{-1})=-4=\det(A^3(B^{-1})^T)$, find $\det A$ and $\det B$.

I'm completely confused how to go about this. I could not find a similar example in my textbook or a theorem.

Comment: $-4=\det(2A^{-1})=8\det(A)^{-1}$, so $\det(A)=-2$.

Comment: I don't see how you got -2, wouldn't it be 1/8?

Comment: $8/-2=-4$, right ?

Comment: @Micky. How do the determinant of $A$ and the determinant of $A^{-1}$ relate?

Comment: @imranfat the question is just written like that. Are you talking about The inverse of a matrix exists if and only if the determinant is non-zero?

Comment: In this question, it is assumed that the matrix is regular. To aid to Dietrich's answer, if you know the determinant of $A^{-1}$, then you know the determinant of $A$ as well.

Answer (score 1):

Using the rule $\det(AB)=\det(A)\det(B)$ for all square matrices $A,B$ of size $n=3$ we get
$$
-4=\det(2A^{-1})=\det(2I_3)\det(A^{-1})=8\det(A)^{-1}.
$$
Here $1=\det(I_3)=\det(AA^{-1})=\det(A)\det(A^{-1})$ again by the above rule, so
$\det(A^{-1})=\det(A)^{-1}$.
Multiply the above line by $\det(A)$ to obtain $-4\det(A)=8$. Then $\det(A)=-2$. A similar argument yields the second part.